# MVC page needs to get data from multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC.

I have a page which display list of categories. The same page also has a text box to search category. What do I need to do in order to use two models in one single page.

```
namespace MvcWebsite.Models.User
{    
    public class ListOfCategories

    {
        public int lngCatId { get; set; }
        public Byte intStatus { get; set; }
        public string txtTitle { get; set; }

        public ListOfCategories()
        {
            intStatus = 1;
        }
    }

    public class SearchBox
    {
        public string txtSearch { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model that incorporates both models - this is called a ViewModel

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public ListOfCategories ListOfCategories { get; set; }
    public SearchBox SearchBox { get; set; }

    // optional method to load data into the viewmodel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel class which contains all the properties required for view.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand from your question is that you want to use properties of both two models from a single page. If that is then you need to use the concept of ViewModels , which is known for the solution of such situations. You simply need to create another which will be some thing like this :

public class ThirdModel
{
    public ListOfCategories ListOfCategories { get; set; } // properties from one model
    public SearchBox SearchBox { get; set; } // properties from second model

}

Now you can access properties of both models in a single model.Thanks